AutoFilter on excel file error 1004 in VBA
My problem persists on this code and I don't understand why.
What the idea behind this code is:

Create a folder on the desktop with the name based on inputs in a UserForm
Copy a file in this folder named exactly as the folder
Select a file containing all the information I need
Select a sheet inside of the file I selected before
Select a value inside of a column inside of the selected sheet to filter everything
Filter all the table inside of my selected file based on the selected value just before
Extract this filtered table as new file on my desktop

My code:
Sub PR_File_Creation()
 
    Dim ENG_File, PR_File, wbk As Workbook
    Dim ENG_Sheet, PR_Sheet, wks, ValveList As Worksheet
    
    Dim desktopPath, destinationPath As String
    Dim folderName, PR_FileName As String
    
    Dim selectedFile As Variant
    Dim selectedSheetName As String
    Dim ValveSheet As String
    Dim selectedItems As String
    Dim selectedSheets As Collection
    Dim uniqueValues As Object
    Dim plageDonnees As Range
    
    Dim ENG_LastLine, PR_LastLine, Valve_LastLine, Valve_LastRow As Long
    
    Dim plageSource, plageDestination As Range
    Dim ligne, colonnes As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim feuille As Variant
    
    Dim fso As Object

    Dim i, j, k, l As Integer
    
    Dim UserForm As PR_File_PRJ_Input
    Dim UserForm2 As Sheet_Selection
    Dim UserForm3 As PRJ_General_Information
    Dim UserForm5 As MultipleSheets_Selection
    Dim UserForm6 As Gr23_Valves_Spec_Selection
    
    Dim url As String
    
    Dim GroupNumber, RevisionNumber, ProjectTrigram As String
    Dim ENG_Header As Long

    ' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
     desktopPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    
    ' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    url = desktopPath & "/TEMPLATE_File.xlsx"
    
    ' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    Set UserForm3 = New PRJ_General_Information
    RemplirGroupENG UserForm3
    
    UserForm3.Show vbModal
    
    ProjectTrigram = UserForm3.TextBox1.Value
    GroupNumber = Split(UserForm3.ComboBox1.Value, "-")(0)
    RevisionNumber = UserForm3.TextBox3.Value
    
    If GroupNumber = "" Then
        MsgBox "You need to enter the Group Number to keep going."
    Exit Sub
    End If
    If ProjectTrigram = "" Then
        MsgBox "You need to enter the Project Trigram to keep going."
    Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    folderName = ProjectTrigram & "_" & GroupNumber & "_PR_File"
    
    PR_FileName = ProjectTrigram & "_Gr" & GroupNumber & "_Rev" & RevisionNumber & "_PR_File.xlsx"

    If fso.FolderExists(desktopPath & Chr(92) & folderName) Then
        MsgBox "A folder named " & ProjectTrigram & "_" & GroupNumber & "_PR_File" & " already exists. " & vbCrLf & _
            "In this folder, you will find the PR File to upload in digiBuy. " & vbCrLf & _
            "In the next window, please select the ENG source file which includes the Engineering information to copy.", vbInformation
        destinationPath = desktopPath & Chr(92) & folderName & Chr(92) & PR_FileName
    Else
        fso.CreateFolder desktopPath & Chr(92) & folderName
        MsgBox "A folder named " & ProjectTrigram & "_" & GroupNumber & "_PR_File" & " has been created on you desktop." & vbCrLf & _
            "In this folder, you will find the PR File to upload in digiBuy." & vbCrLf & _
            "In the next window, please select the ENG source file which includes the Engineering information to copy.", vbInformation
        destinationPath = desktopPath & Chr(92) & folderName & Chr(92) & PR_FileName
    End If
    
    folderName = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & Chr(92) & ProjectTrigram & "_" & GroupNumber & "_PR_File"
    
    destinationPath = folderName & "\" & PR_FileName

    If Len(Dir(destinationPath)) > 0 Then
        MsgBox PR_FileName & " already exists." & vbCrLf & _
            "You need to delete " & PR_FileName & " to Continue." & vbCrLf & _
            "After the deletion, you'll have to restart the PR File Creation Macro"
    Else
        DownloadFileFromURL url, destinationPath
        selectedFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls; *.xlsx; *xlsm), *.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm", _
        , "Please select the ENG source file which includes the Engineering information to copy.")
 
    If selectedFile = False Then Exit Sub
    End If

    DownloadFileFromURL url, destinationPath
    Set ENG_File = Workbooks.Open(selectedFile)
    
    ' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    If GroupNumber = "21" Or GroupNumber = "23" Or GroupNumber = "65" Then
        Set UserForm2 = New Sheet_Selection
            For Each ws In ENG_File.Sheets
                UserForm2.ComboBox1.AddItem ws.Name
            Next ws
        
        UserForm2.Show vbModal
        
        selectedSheetName = UserForm2.ComboBox1.Value
        On Error Resume Next
            Set ENG_Sheet = ENG_File.Sheets(selectedSheetName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ENG_Sheet Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "La feuille spécifiée n'a pas été trouvée dans le fichier sélectionné.", vbExclamation
            ENG_File.Close False
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    Set PR_File = Workbooks.Open(folderName & Chr(92) & PR_FileName)
    Set PR_Sheet = PR_File.Sheets(1)
    
    ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' ---------------------- Gr15 ---------------------------
    If GroupNumber = "15" Then
    '  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' ---------------------- Gr23 VALVES BUT NOT LBV or SBV---------------------------
    ElseIf GroupNumber = "23" Then

    ENG_Header = 15

    ValveSheet = UserForm2.ComboBox1.Value
    Set ValveList = ENG_File.Worksheets(ValveSheet)
    Valve_LastLine = ValveList.Cells(ValveList.Rows.Count, "AO").End(xlUp).Row '
    Valve_LastRow = ValveList.Cells(ENG_Header, ValveList.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    
    Set UserForm6 = New Gr23_Valves_Spec_Selection
    Set uniqueValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For Each cell In ValveList.Range("AO" & ENG_Header & ":AO" & Valve_LastLine)
        If Not uniqueValues.Exists(cell.Value) Then
            uniqueValues.Add cell.Value, cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
        
    For Each Key In uniqueValues.Keys
        UserForm6.ListBox1.AddItem Key
    Next Key
    
    UserForm6.ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectExtended
    UserForm6.Show vbModal

    For i = 0 To UserForm6.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If UserForm6.ListBox1.selected(i) Then
            selectedItems = selectedItems & UserForm6.ListBox1.List(i) & ","
        End If
    Next i

    If Len(selectedItems) > 0 Then
        selectedItems = Left(selectedItems, Len(selectedItems) - 1)
    End If

    Set plageDonnes = ENG_File.Worksheets(ValveSheet).Range("A" & ENG_Header, ENG_File.Worksheets(ValveSheet).Cells(Valve_LastLine, Valve_LastRow))
    Debug.Print ("A" & ENG_Header)
    Debug.Print (ENG_File.Worksheets(ValveSheet).Cells(Valve_LastLine, Valve_LastRow))
    

    Dim criteriaArray() As String
    criteriaArray = Split(selectedItems, ",")

    plageDonnes.AutoFilter _
        Field:=41, _
        Criteria1:=CStr(criteriaArray), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues

        
    Dim filtreActif As Boolean
    filtreActif = ValveList.AutoFilterMode
    
    ' Copier les données filtrées dans un nouveau classeur
    Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
    Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
    
    With newWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Paste
        .Name = "FilteredData"
    End With
    
    newWorkbook.SaveAs desktopPath & "Valve_extracted.xlsx"
    newWorkbook.Close False
    
    End If
End sub

Everything works until:
    plageDonnes.AutoFilter _
        Field:=41, _
        Criteria1:=CStr(criteriaArray), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues

which does not wants to work at all.
the debugger just gives me an error *1004 AutoFilter method of Range class failed
*
I tried a few things but nothing seems to work so that's why I'm seeking help here.
There is way more variables than what is required inside of my code because I just brought an extract from it to show it to you (everything after my problems have been deleted)
I'm sorry if my code is not well structured or written, I'm a beginner in VBA (and I also welcome any advice)

CStr(criteriaArray) looks problematic.

Also, you are not dealing with the case when Len(selectedItems) = 0, e.g. message box and exit.

@BigBen Even if I try directly a String such as "water" (wihch is in the column) it does not work

@VBasic2008 Yeah ty, I forgot about that, just added something to handle this

What does Debug.Print plageDonnes.Address return?

@BigBen it gives me $A$15:$A$728 which is the size of my first column

So your problem is Field:=41 I'd guess.

@BigBen I changed and defined my Range manualy (not using variables) and it looks like it work !
